# catch error of my exported async/await function

Tags: javascript, node.js, error-handling, backend

I have module that check username is unique or no!
my module is:

```js
// Check for uniqueness username
const UsernameUniqueness = async (_username) => {

    const username = await Users.findOne({
        username: _username
    });

    if (username) {
        return false;
    }

    return true;

}

exports.UsernameUniqueness = UsernameUniqueness;
```

and I have a route that I post username to it.

```js
const FormUniqueness = require('../modules/form-uniqueness');

router.post('/register', redirectDashboard, async (req, res, next) => {
  const ( username } = req.body;
  
  try {
    console.log(FormUniqueness.UsernameUniqueness(userName));

  } catch (error) {
        // Internal server error 500
        console.log('here');
        error.status = 500;
        next(error);
  }
  

}
```

I want when I have an error in "const username = await Users.findOne({
username: _username
}); my error throw in try/catch of my route!"

How can I do this?

Comment: `console.log(await FormUniqueness.UsernameUniqueness(userName))`

Answer (score 0):

Catch the error also in your function

```
const UsernameUniqueness = async (_username) => {

    try {
   

        const username = await Users.findOne({
            username: _username
        });

        if (username) {
            return false;
        }

        return true;

    } catch(error) {
        throw error;
    }
}

exports.UsernameUniqueness = UsernameUniqueness;
```